# Computing $\int_0^\infty {r\over(r^2+d^2-2urd)^{(3/2)}}dr$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I am trying to find the integral
$$\int_0^\infty {r\over(r^2+d^2-2urd)^{(3/2)}}dr$$
The answer is given by
$${\frac{ru-d}{d(1-u^2)\sqrt{r^2+d^2-2rud}}}\bigg]_0^\infty.$$

I am unable to connect to this answer.
Could anyone please give some hints

Comment: Can you specify what $r$, $d$, and $u$ are? If they are real numbers, this integral seems to diverge according to https://www.integral-calculator.com/.

Comment: They are just real numbers, u can in between -1 and 1, d is also a real number @Accelerator

Comment: But Wolfgram alpha integral calculator gives the same result as I written@Accelerator

Comment: I think that you have to give the restriction $|u|<1$.

Comment: Right, already in the problem itself $|u|<1$ @JeanMarie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, we are trying to find:

$$\mathcal{I}_{\space\text{n}}\left(\text{k}\right):=\int_0^\infty\frac{x}{\left(x^2+\text{k}x+\text{n}\right)^\frac{3}{2}}\space\text{d}x\tag1$$

First we can use partial fractions in order to write:

$$\frac{x}{\left(x^2+\text{k}x+\text{n}\right)^\frac{3}{2}}=\frac{2x+\text{k}}{2\left(x^2+\text{k}x+\text{n}\right)^\frac{3}{2}}-\frac{\text{k}}{2\left(x^2+\text{k}x+\text{n}\right)^\frac{3}{2}}\tag2$$

So:

$$\mathcal{I}_{\space\text{n}}\left(\text{k}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\underbrace{\int_0^\infty\frac{2x+\text{k}}{2\left(x^2+\text{k}x+\text{n}\right)^\frac{3}{2}}\space\text{d}x}_{:=\space\mathscr{I}_{1\space\text{|}\space\text{n}}\left(\text{k}\right)}-\frac{\text{k}}{2}\underbrace{\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{\left(x^2+\text{k}x+\text{n}\right)^\frac{3}{2}}\space\text{d}x}_{:=\space\mathscr{I}_{2\space\text{|}\space\text{n}}\left(\text{k}\right)}\tag3$$

Now, let's substitute $\text{u}=x^2+\text{k}x+\text{n}$ for $\mathscr{I}_{1\space\text{|}\space\text{n}}\left(\text{k}\right)$ which gives:

$$\mathscr{I}_{1\space\text{|}\space\text{n}}\left(\text{k}\right)=\int_\text{n}^\infty\frac{1}{\text{u}^\frac{3}{2}}\space\text{du}=\lim_{\text{m}\space\to\space\infty}\left[-\frac{2}{\sqrt{\text{u}}}\right]_\text{n}^\text{m}=\lim_{\text{m}\space\to\space\infty}\left(-\frac{2}{\sqrt{\text{m}}}\right)-\left(-\frac{2}{\sqrt{\text{n}}}\right)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\text{n}}}\tag4$$

Completing the scare we can see that:

$$\frac{1}{\left(x^2+\text{k}x+\text{n}\right)^\frac{3}{2}}=\frac{1}{\left(\left(x+\frac{\text{k}}{2}\right)^2+\text{n}-\frac{\text{k}^2}{4}\right)^\frac{3}{2}}=\frac{8}{\left(\left(2x+\text{k}\right)^2+4\text{n}-\text{k}^2\right)^\frac{3}{2}}\tag5$$

Now, let's substitute $\text{s}=2x+\text{k}$ for $\mathscr{I}_{2\space\text{|}\space\text{n}}\left(\text{k}\right)$ which gives:

$$\mathscr{I}_{2\space\text{|}\space\text{n}}\left(\text{k}\right)=\frac{8}{2}\int_\text{k}^\infty\frac{1}{\left(\text{s}^2+4\text{n}-\text{k}^2\right)^\frac{3}{2}}\space\text{ds}=4\int_\text{k}^\infty\frac{1}{\left(\text{s}^2+4\text{n}-\text{k}^2\right)^\frac{3}{2}}\space\text{ds}\tag6$$

Now, let's substitute $\text{u}=\sqrt{4\text{n}-\text{k}^2}\tan\left(\text{p}\right)$ for $\mathscr{I}_{2\space\text{|}\space\text{n}}\left(\text{k}\right)$ which gives:

$$\mathscr{I}_{2\space\text{|}\space\text{n}}\left(\text{k}\right)=\frac{4}{4\text{n}-\text{k}^2}\int_\sigma^\frac{\pi}{2}\underbrace{\frac{1}{\sec\left(\text{p}\right)}}_{=\space\cos\left(\text{p}\right)}\space\text{dp}=\frac{4}{4\text{n}-\text{k}^2}\cdot\left[\sin\left(\text{p}\right)\right]_\sigma^\frac{\pi}{2}=\frac{4\left(1-\sin\left(\sigma\right)\right)}{4\text{n}-\text{k}^2}\tag7$$

Where $\sigma:=\arctan\left(\frac{\text{k}}{\sqrt{4\text{n}-\text{k}^2}}\right)$.

So, we end up with:

$$\mathcal{I}_{\space\text{n}}\left(\text{k}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{2}{\sqrt{\text{n}}}-\frac{\text{k}}{2}\cdot\frac{4\left(1-\sin\left(\sigma\right)\right)}{4\text{n}-\text{k}^2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\text{n}}}-\frac{2\text{k}\left(1-\sin\left(\sigma\right)\right)}{4\text{n}-\text{k}^2}\tag8$$

Now, you can use the fact that $\sin\left(\arctan\left(x\right)\right)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$.

> I'll let you finish.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\int {x\over(x^2+d^2-2uxd)^{3/2}}dx=\frac{Ax+B}{\sqrt{z^2+d^2-2udx}}$$
D.w.r.t. $x$, then
$$\frac{x}{\over(x^2+d^2-2uxd)^{3/2}}=\frac{d}{dx}\frac{Ax+B}{\sqrt{z^2+d^2-2udx}}$$
$$\implies \frac{1x+0}{\over(x^2+d^2-2uxd)^{3/2}}=\frac{A(x^2+d^2-2udx)-2(ax+b)(x-ud)}{(x^2+d^2-2udx)^{3/2}}$$
On comparing the coefficient of $x$ and constant term in above get $A$ an $B$ in terns of $u,d$. Then do the definite integral part.

Answer (score 0):

Integrate
\begin{align}
& \int d\left({r\over(r^2+d^2-2urd)^{1/2}}\right)\\
=& \int {{d^2(1-u^2)}\over(r^2+d^2-2urd)^{3/2}}
- {{ud(r-ud)}\over(r^2+d^2-2urd)^{3/2}}\ dr
\end{align}
which leads to
\begin{align}
&\int{1\over(r^2+d^2-2urd)^{3/2}}dr
=\frac{r-ud}{d^2(1-u^2)\sqrt{r^2+d^2-2rud}}\\
\end{align}
Substitute $r\to \frac dr$ to obtain
\begin{align}
&\int{r\over(r^2+d^2-2urd)^{3/2}}dr
={\frac{ru-d}{d(1-u^2)\sqrt{r^2+d^2-2rud}}}\\
\end{align}